# Is there an NFC API for the Sony SmartWatch 2?

Tags: nfc, sony, sony-smartwatch

We want to write an Android App for the Sony SmartWatch 2 which uses the device's NFC functionality to read and write NFC tags (such as Mifare or DESfire cards). NFC functionality is heavily promoted for the SmartWatch 2, however, I couldn't find any information on an open NFC API so far.

My questions: Is there an open NFC API for the SmartWatch 2? If so, are there any restrictions on the mode of communication (Reader/Writer mode vs. P2P)? Where can I find related documentation?

Thanks,
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NFC in the SW2 is only used for pairing it to a phone. Sony does not support any API to read tags or transfer data using the NFC in the watch.

Comment: Thanks! Where do you have this information from? Is there anything official available on this?

Comment: Check out the API reference http://developer.sonymobile.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/packages