# Transfer data between smartwatch using nfc

Tags: android, nfc, sony-smartwatch

Is it possible to transfer data between smart watch 3 using nfc API. I have checked [development](https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/develop-android-wear-apps-for-smartwatch-3/) and [sdk API](https://developer.sony.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/packages). can we have any api or sdk for smartwatch3 that can transfer data between two smartwatch3 using NFC?

Comment: did you try checking the official NFC guide: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html ?? I mean, AndroidWear is a slimmed down version of Android but does all the normal APIs, NFC, Sensors, etc

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an NFC API for the Smartwatch 3 (SWR50)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769864/is-there-an-nfc-api-for-the-smartwatch-3-swr50)