# Read NFC tags with Sony Smartwatch 3 (SWR50)

Tags: android, nfc, wear-os, sony-smartwatch

For the past day i have been reading about the NFC support for the Sony Smartwatch 3 (the main reason i got one). It got me confused. There is not much out there.

One of the best references i could find is 1,5 years old: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27483125/559333. 
If i read it and this http://androidcommunity.com/heres-how-to-enable-sony-smartwatch-3s-nfc-feature-20151009/ it seems to me the hardware capable of using/reading NFC. There has been some updates. So my hope is that there is some change within the last 1,5 years but i can't find anything about it.

I want to place some tags around the house and trigger something by sending the tag id to my server when i hold the watch next to it.

Does anyone know if/how this would be possible with current firmware of a hack?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an NFC API for the Smartwatch 3 (SWR50)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769864/is-there-an-nfc-api-for-the-smartwatch-3-swr50)

Comment: I'm aware that you referenced exactly this question in your post. Unfortunately, that's still valid with the latest firmware: There is no usable NFC (other than the tag that is emulated by the watch for pairing) unless you use the hack/firmware customization that you already linked.

Comment: True, but commenting on the original question would not have got me the answer (thanks for that). But it's still a duplicate. (If i may a little followup question). Is there any official NFC support for android wear? Do you think there will be a update in the future for supporting NFC (for the SWE50)? I put a question to Sony support about that. Lets see what they say. If they replay with anything interesting ill post it here.

Comment: I guess that's something that only Sony might be able to answer.

Comment: And NFC support for wear is not officially there right?

Comment: The Android NFC API is available in Android Wear but I don't see anything that would force manufacturers to integrate NFC in any Android device (regardless of phone, tablet, wearable, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, as long as nobody implements it in there device. Nobody will make apps for it and nobody will request the feature. So lets hope it will change. I know that android has NFC support. But i can't find any reference to it about wear. Do you have a link for it? Because i can't find any reference for it.